# Find invalid dates in DataTable Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` (that was loaded from EXCEL) with a Date column.

I need to validate that the date column is valid, and if not return number of invalid dates.

For example:

```
Col1  ColDate
---------------
k1     21/11/2016

k2     25/10/1975

k3     31/2/2016

k4     abcd
```

The above table should return 2 (cause the last two rows contains invalid dates).

How can I find the invalid rows using LINQ

Comment: You could loop through trying doing a parse date to see if it lets you

Comment: I tried it using LINQ, and in above example, All records returns as NOT a date

Comment: Well, first post the code that is doing it without using LINQ, then ask for LINQ translation if you still can't make it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I Hope This Code Help You.

```
 string[] dates = { "10-10-2015", "41-50-5880", "awewe" };

        foreach (var Date in dates)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(Date));
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invaid Date");
            }
        }
```

**Output**

```
10/10/2015 12:00:00 AM
Invaid Date
Invaid Date
```

**Using Linq**

```
  var Dates = (from dd in dates                     
                 select WE(dd)).ToList();
```

**Add Function**

```
public static string WE(string Date)
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(Date).ToString();
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            return "Invalid Date";
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
10/10/2015 12:00:00 AM
Invaid Date
Invaid Date
```

Comment: Thanks, Im looking for a way to do it using LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Following LINQ should do the work. You can also pass a `CultureInfo` to `TryParse` method if using the invariant culture is not suitable for you.

```
DateTime date;
var itemsWithInvalidDates = items.Where(item => !DateTime.TryParse(item.ColDate, out date))
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really sure, that all your dates do have this format, try this out (code assumes, that you  do have your data as collection of strings):

```
string[] dates = { "21/11/2016", "25/10/1975", "31/2/2016", "asdad" };
var result = dates.Count(x =>
{
    DateTime val;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out val);
})
```

if `31/2/2016` is not valid date, but `01/2/2016` is valid, you should update query to:

```
dates.Count(x =>
{
    DateTime val;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy",            
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out val)
    || DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "dd/M/yyyy", 
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out val) ; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date.TryParse in LINQ condition.[Example with code](http://rextester.com/LFJJP67660)

```
     public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //Your code goes here
        DataTable  datatable = GetDataTable(); 
        DateTime date ;
        var dataRows = datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(myRow => DateTime.TryParse(myRow.Field<String>("ColDate"), out date));

       foreach ( DataRow row in dataRows)
        Console.WriteLine(row["ColDate"]);
    }
```